Colorize Specific Regions of an Image Using a Mask with ImageMagick
I'm trying to colorize specific regions of an image based on a mask using ImageMagick. The mask contains white pixels where the image should be colorized and black pixels where no colorization should occur.
The command I've tried:
magick convert input_image.png mask.png -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite -fill "#FF5733" -colorize 100% output_image.png

Problem:

the entire image is getting colorized instead of only the white areas defined by the mask.

System Info:

OS: Windows 10
ImageMagick version: 7.1.0-27


Here is one way to do that in Imagemagick. Create a colorized image the size of the input. Then use the mask to composite them together.
(Don't use magick convert --- use just magick)
Image:

Mask:

magick lena.png ( +clone -fill blue -colorize 100 ) mask.png -compose over -composite lena_colorized.png


